# 18.04: can't run GRUB customizer

Tags: 18.04, grub2

I reinstalled Ubuntu because my dual boot system for some reason didn't work anymore.

GRUB is corrupted, and I'm trying to fix it with [GRUB Customizer](https://itsfoss.com/grub-customizer-ubuntu/) which fails with:[grub fail messsage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g41z.png)

> /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'.

How do I troubleshoot this to solve the GRUB error?

Thanks for the edit, I have an update

So i realized i was missing grub entirely for some reason and installed it myself.
My instalation was missing a device.map which i was able to make using grub-mkdevice.
[grub costumizer requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Ht9.png)
but it was also missing a config when i tried to use grub mk-config i got the same error

[error when trying to create config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0U3g.png)

Comment: Were you booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB when you got these errors? Don't run GRUB Customizer... it won't FIX your problem, only make it worse. Describe what you mean by "GRUB is corrupted". Did the reinstall go OK? Can you boot now?

Comment: /cow is copy on write, or the live installer. You cannot update live installer. Often better to use Boot-Repair and just run report and ask for help from that. Sometimes its autofix makes things worse so best to ask first. But if simple issue, it usually works. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair